# External Libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, libraries

Is there any way to add external python libraries in visual studio code? I have a folder of modules that my teacher provided that I need to write the program. I know how to do this in eclipse, but is there an option to do it in vscode?

Comment: What do you mean "add"? If you have the source you just need to put it somewhere Python can import it. There's nothing special you have to do for VS Code as it just executes Python directly (IOW there's no project file like in Eclipse which require listing your dependencies).